# Ошибка при установке библиотеки sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Отправляю в cmd  `>>> pip install sqlite3`

Взамен я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from ver
sions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
```

Как я знаю библиотека sqlite3 есть в установочном пакете Python..

Решил написать код для проверки наличия sqlite3:

```py
import sqlite3
dir(sqlite3)
```

Но, командная строка отправляет мне пустую строку:

```
C:\Users\Admin>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>python sqlite.py

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>
```

*Использую python 3.8.6, версия pip'а 20.2.4*

Comment: вам бы вывести результат  через print ) `print(dir(sqlite3))`

Comment: Как писали выше нужен print) для наглядности. Но и так у вас все ок sqlite работает. Иначе бы  при запуске скрипта сыпались ошибки на импорт. А ошибка pip на то что он не может найти подходящую версию.

Comment: `sqlite3` - невозможно установить при помощи команды `pip`, т.к. `sqlite3` - модуль, входящий в стандартную установку Python - т.е. тот который установлен по умолчанию.

Comment: Меня смущает приглашение ввода в данной строке: `>>> pip install sqlite3`. Это приглашение самого интерпретатора python. Вы уверены, что ничего не перепутали? При вводе данной строки в `cmd.exe` строка ввода выглядела бы иначе: `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop > pip install sqlite3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете установить библиотеку так как она уже предустановлена (входит в стандартную библиотеку). вы можете просто импортировать её и пользоваться.